# How can I access an IPv6-only host from a Windows 7 computer behind an IPv4-NAT?

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, nat, teredo

I have a computer with Windows 7. It's connected to Internet via an IPv4 NAT router. How can I access a host that is only accessible with IPv6?

Is there an easy way to configure the Windows 7 Teredo tunnel for this? or how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

1. Get a native IPv6 connection (most recommended).

   or
2. Do tunneling.

   1. via [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/), [he.net](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/) or any other tunnel broker (recommended)
   2. via 6to4 (might be unstable and thus not recommended). Here, your IPv6 is assembled of `2002:aabb:ccdd::`, where `aa`, `bb`, `cc` and `dd` are the hex representations of the octets in your IPv4. Maybe [this](http://www.cellstream.com/intranet/tipsandtricks/250-setting-up-a-6to4-tunnel-in-windows-7.html) might help.
   3. via Teredo (don't know how that works)

Answer (score 0):

Teredo should work out of the box, but is disabled by default if the computer is a member of a Windows domain.

The IPv6 only host must reply to pings, and the teredo relay is chosen by IPv6 routing from the IPv6-only host.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how to activate Teredo in your answer.